# Django Generic Views :How does DetailView automatically provides the variable to the template ??

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

In the following code, How does the template `details.html` knows that `album` is passed to it by `views.py` although we have never returned or defined any `context_object_name` in `DetailsView` class in `views.py`. 
Please explain how are the various things getting connected here.

`details.html`

```
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %}AlbumDetails{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <img src="{{ album.album_logo }}" style="width: 250px;">
    <h1>{{ album.album_title }}</h1>
    <h3>{{ album.artist }}</h3>

    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
        {{ song.song_title }}
        {% if song.is_favourite %}
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png" />
        {% endif %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`views.py`

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Album

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'music/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'album_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()

class DetailsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Album
    template_name = 'music/details.html'
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [

    # /music/
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # /music/album_id/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailsView.as_view(), name='details'),

]
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the implementation of `get_context_name()`, you'll see this:

```
def get_context_object_name(self, obj):
    """
    Get the name to use for the object.
    """
    if self.context_object_name:
        return self.context_object_name
    elif isinstance(obj, models.Model):
        return obj._meta.model_name
    else:
        return None
```

And the implementation for `get_context_data()` (from `SingleObjectMixin`):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Insert the single object into the context dict.
    """
    context = {}
    if self.object:
        context['object'] = self.object
        context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
        if context_object_name:
            context[context_object_name] = self.object
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super(SingleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

So you can see that `get_context_data()` adds to the dictionary an entry with the key `context_object_name` (from `get_context_object_name()`) which returns `obj._meta.model_name` when `self.context_object_name` isn't defined. In this case, the view got `self.object` as a consequence of the call to `get()` which calls `get_object()`. `get_object()` takes the model that you've defined and automatically queries it from your database using the `pk` you've defined in your `urls.py` file.

http://ccbv.co.uk/ is a very good website for seeing all of the functions and attributes the class based views of Django has to offer in a single page.

Comment: This means if I would have used some other variable name instead of `album` in `details.html`, it won't work and I have to define the variable using context_object_name explicitly, right ?

Comment: Also can you please tell me when does `get_context_name()` gets called ?

Comment: @lordzuko, to your first comment, yes :) The name of the variable is determined by the your model name. You can define it explicitly, yes.

`get_context_name()` gets called in the `get()` method which gets called whenever the view receives a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful where if context_object_name is not set, the context name will be constructed from the model_name of the model that the queryset is composed from

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name